# R: Get x neighbours from a dataframe based on column value

Tags: r, performance, search, numbers

I wrote a function which I provide with a number which then gives me x rows having a numerical value close to the input number.

For example this is the dataframe:

```
test.data <- data.frame(
  number = c(0,1,3,4,6,2,7,1,3,3,4,0,1,6), 
  letter = letters[1:14]
)
```

Then I wrote this function to give me the neighbors:

```
# library(dplyr)
get.closest <- function( input.number, n.closest, data ) {
  data %>% 
    mutate(abs.score.dif = abs(input.number - number)) %>%
    arrange(abs.score.dif) %>%
    head(n.closest)
}
```

So for example `get.closest(6, 3, test.data)` will give me:

```
  number letter abs.score.dif rel.score.dif
1      6      e             0             0
2      6      n             0             0
3      7      g             1            -1
```

However I have to do this for **> 20.000 numbers and my data frame is around 20.000 rows as well, making this really slow**. How can this be done faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
N = 6
n = 3
df_out = transform(test.data[head(order(abs(N - test.data$number)), n),],
                   abs.diff = abs(N - number),
                   rel.diff = N - number)
df_out
#   number letter abs.diff rel.diff
#5       6      e        0        0
#14      6      n        0        0
#7       7      g        1       -1
```

Seems to be fast with following data

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
test.data = data.frame(number = sample(0:10, 200000, TRUE),
                       letter = sample(letters, 200000, TRUE))
```